# eager load of relations of a specific model in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model named `Test` like this:

```
class Test extends Model
{
    public    $primaryKey = 'test_id';
    public function questions ()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question', 'question_test', 'test_id', 'question_id');
    }
}
```

And a `Question` model like this:

```
class Question extends Model
{
    public function tests ()
    {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Test', 'question_test', 'question_id', 'test_id');
    }
}
```

As you see there is a `ManyToMany` relation between this two model.

Now in a controller function, I want to get an specific Test(by id) and send it to a view. then eager load all it's `questions` related models and send it to another view. like this :

```
public function beginTest ($course_id, $lesson_id, $test_id)
        {

                $test = Test::find($test_id);


                if ($test->onebyone) {

                    return view('main/pages/test/test-onebyone', compact('test'));

                } else {

                    $test = $test->with('questions.options')->get();
                    return view('main/pages/test/test-onepage', compact('test', 'done_test_id'));

                }
            }
        }
```

Problem is that when I use `with()` laravel method to eager load relations, it return all Test models with their `Question` relations while I want to get relations of selected `Test` model only.

what is your solution to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use 'lazy eager loading'.

```
$test->load('questions.options');
```

Using `with` off the model instance will make it use a new builder and cause a new query to be executed.